# 1 service 1 Database Pattern is not required anymore when using cockroachDB

Tags: database-design, architecture, microservices, cockroachdb

Since cockroachDB is scalable RDBMS, as per my understanding we do not need the Master-Slave pattern anymore, since every request will be served equally by each node.

However, do we still need 1 service 1 database pattern?

We could just replicate and scale our monolithic service when our database is cockroachDB. Since mostly the bottleneck is in the database itself. Is this a valid argument?

How about multiple service with shared database (using cockroachDB), is this scalable?

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the 1 service 1 database pattern. It's not about data replication, it's about bounded context and coupling.

Comment: Some related discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72153570/can-distributed-sql-tools-be-applied-as-alternatives-to-2-phase-commit-or-sagas/72177805

Answer (score 2):

You can get (most of) the best of both worlds by modifying the pattern slightly: use one CockroachDB *cluster*, but with one *database* per service. This lets you avoid the pain of managing the infrastructure and deployment of multiple databases, but enforces logical decoupling between services.